# Python 3.10.12 debugger locks up system when debugging kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

When running a kivyMD file (main.py) within the Python debugger my system is totally croaking at my break point line.

I tested the debugger against a previously developed application (just Python & tkinter), set a break point and the debugger worked as expected.  Looks like something with kivyMD the debugger doesn't like.

Environment: (virtual env)

Python: 3.10.12
kivyMD: 1.1.1
kivy: 2.2.1
Pycharm Community: 2023.2
ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (desktop)

Program main.py which uses a main.kv runs just fine but attempting to debug it within Pycharm or not totally locks up my system requiring a reboot.

Anyone hear of such a thing ? I'll check my logs to see if anything jumps out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What operating system, and do you have a source code?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop